# Button as a file field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, input, filefield

I need a button that can be fully customised via css to prompt the user to select a file for upload when clicked. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want an input of file type, you can just add the field to your markup:

```
<input type="file" name="name_of_attribute" />
```

You can hook into it using css:

```
input[type='file'] {
  height: 9001px;
}
```

There are methods in rails to generate the markup for you, have a look at the `file_field` method http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-file_field or `file_field_tag` method here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-file_field_tag

Make sure you make your form multipart or you'll have problems uploading the file using the input.